# Using AWK to extract one column from a tab separated file

Tags: awk

I know this is a simple question, but the awk command is literally melting my brain. I have a tab separated file "inputfile.gtf" and I need to extract one column from it and put it into a new file "newfile.tsv" I cannot for the life of me figure out the proper syntax to do this with awk. Here is what I've tried:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="/t"} {print $8}'  inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

also

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="/t";FS="/t"};{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

Both of these just give me an empty file. Everywhere I search, people seem to have completely different ways of trying to achieve this simple task, and at this point I am completely lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the wrong delimiter `/t`, the *tab* character typed as `\t`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }{ print $8 }' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simpler :

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method. I've been so confused, because none of the awk guides I've found online do a good job of explaining the syntax of the command. So it seems there are many ways to do the same thing, and they all look completely different to me. Coding newbie here as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your **1st** command :

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS="/t"} {print $8}'  inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

You are setting `-F,` which is not required, as your file is not `,` comma separated.

next, `OFS="/t"` : Syntax is incorrect, it should be `OFS="\t"`, but again you don't need this as you don't want to set Output fields separator as `\t` since you're printing only a single record and OFS is not at all involved in this case;  unless you print atleast two fields.

Your **2nd** command :

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="/t";FS="/t"};{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

Again it's not `/t` it should be `\t`.  Also `FS="\t"` is similar to `-F "\t"`

**What you actually need is :**

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

or

```
awk -v FS="\t" '{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```

And if your file has just `tabs` and your fields don't have spaces in between then you can simply use :

```
awk '{print $8}' inputfile.gtf  > newfile.tsv
```